# Restrict Visual Studio Online Git Permissions by repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have several projects in my Visual Studio Online's DefaultCollection. One of them is a Git project. Within that project I have several Git repos. I have multiple contractors working on various projects within there. I want to be able to allow a user specific permissions only against a single repo.

I setup how I thought the permissions should be under Version Control > git repo, and added the user to the appropriate branch and provided read and contribute permissions. However, if I leave that as is then they cannot see the actual project under my DefaultCollection. I then add them to my "Team" under the Security tab with base permissions. With that added they are able to see the project but are able to interact with ALL of my Git repos instead of the single one I explicitly provided permissions to.

How can I set it up so a user or group can only interact with a single Git repo instead of the entire project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't hire people that you don't trust.

Second, you can remove permissions as well as add them. So you can remove the default permission and explicitly add. On each Git repo remove R+W for Contributor and explicitly add your Team. Then give contractor's permission only to that repo.

Comment: Thanks @MrHinsh, works great. To your comment about not trusting... it's not about that at all 1) it's never a bad idea to deny your people the ability to screw up, even on accident, we've all made mistakes and seen accidents happen 2) there's a gang of different projects in here and some just don't apply to everyone / shouldn't show up in their available repo list